# Advantage of t4 templates over Class files

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, t4

What is the advantage of t4 templates over Class files in asp.net?

Like we are generating strongly typed class using t4 templates. We can do the same using c# class files in asp.net. So, what is the advantage of t4 template over normal class files?

Anyone please point out the scenerio wher t4 can be implemented over class files.

Regards,
Sujith

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this quote taken from a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) tutorial:

> a T4 text template is a mixture of text blocks and control logic that can generate a text file. The control logic is written as fragments of program code in Visual C# or Visual Basic. The generated file can be text of any kind, such as a Web page, or a resource file, or program source code in any language.

T4 templates are used to generate dynamic text, that can be even a class. The entity framework or the DataSet Designer are good examples of Design-Time Code Generation by allowing the user to graphically drag and drop entities from a database to a Designer and then generating all the classes to reflect your database tables.

Under the hood a custom tool transform the generated design time XML in C# classes. The mechanism behind this is similar to what a T4 template does.

hope this overview can give you a better understanding on how T4 templates can come into help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code that writes other code.  There are things that you can not refactor into a single location, or things that are just more easily centralized via T4 (or any code generation).

There may be code where one central driver could need multiple files or lots of code in a single file to be changed based on that.

Another way to make good use of it... I used a `T4` template to write a little C# object that generates a `.sql` file, a `.xsl`, a `.js` and `.cs` file. All from the single C# object based on a set of rules. So I'm generating several useful files off of one c# template. I could have it generating the .sql needed to create a table to hold that type. a .xsl or .xml to define configuration values related to the item, a .js file to bring a strongly typed model into javascript, and finally .cs for the actual model in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, T4 templates can generate classes for you (and other files) based on some input data like an Entity Framework model. This is very handy in cases where you have to create many classes (like classes for all entities of a large Entity Framework model) with identical features. The T4 template then just does the job and updates the created classes automatically if the input is altered (you can run the "Custom Tool" on the input file to execute the T4 template as well).

The T4 template can (of course) create partial classes to allow you to add members (to other parts of the class that you create). This way you can add functionality that is not overwritten when the template recreates the classes.

The T4 templates that generate POCO classes (default for EF in .NET 4.5) bases on a EF model are a perfect example for a good usage of T4 templates. Another example would be a T4 template that creates view model  base classes (for MVVM) for all entity classes of an EF model.